# MySQL crashes because out of memory

Tags: mysql, out-of-memory

On my website VPS the MySQL goes down quite often, once a day lately.

I've looked in my syslog and seems like it is an Out Of Memory error.

Is my MySQL not configured the right way or is does my VPS not have enough memory for what I'm running on it?

Here are free and top:

```
$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           512        360        151          0          0         42
-/+ buffers/cache:        317        194
Swap:            0          0          0


top - 14:17:47 up 15 days,  9:41,  2 users,  load average: 0.13, 0.30, 0.42
Tasks:  58 total,   1 running,  57 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 19.7%us,  2.7%sy,  0.0%ni, 77.6%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:    524508k total,   415200k used,   109308k free,        0k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,    72404k cached
```

In my.cnf:

```
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
```

I'm using 
`mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.66, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.1`
on
`Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.7 (squeeze)`

Here is the block from my syslog:

```
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.730776] mysqld invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x1201d2, order=0, oomkilladj=0
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.730789] Pid: 13220, comm: mysqld Not tainted 2.6.24-19-xen #1
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.730791] 
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.730792] Call Trace:
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.730802]  [<ffffffff80275e26>] oom_kill_process+0xf6/0x110
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.730806]  [<ffffffff802762ae>] out_of_memory+0x19e/0x1e0
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.730810]  [<ffffffff80278bd9>] __alloc_pages+0x389/0x3c0
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.730815]  [<ffffffff8027af54>] __do_page_cache_readahead+0x104/0x260
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.730818]  [<ffffffff8027520e>] filemap_fault+0x2de/0x3e0
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.730822]  [<ffffffff80281f3a>] __do_fault+0x6a/0x5d0
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.730824]  [<ffffffff80287551>] handle_mm_fault+0x1d1/0xd60
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.730829]  [<ffffffff80229f63>] set_next_entity+0x23/0x50
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.730835]  [<ffffffff80473553>] do_page_fault+0x1f3/0x11e0
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.730840]  [<ffffffff8046f7e9>] thread_return+0x3a/0x481
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.730845]  [<ffffffff80471bf7>] error_exit+0x0/0x79
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.730848] 
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.730850] Mem-info:
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.730851] DMA per-cpu:
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.730853] CPU    0: Hot: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0   Cold: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.730855] DMA32 per-cpu:
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.730857] CPU    0: Hot: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 172   Cold: hi:   62, btch:  15 usd:  14
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.730861] Active:94084 inactive:618 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.730861]  free:4898 slab:3594 mapped:0 pagetables:3925 bounce:0
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.730866] DMA free:11540kB min:28kB low:32kB high:40kB active:0kB inactive:0kB present:16160kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.730869] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 4024 4024 4024
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.730875] DMA32 free:8052kB min:8100kB low:10124kB high:12148kB active:376336kB inactive:2472kB present:4120800kB pages_scanned:767723 all_unreclaimable? yes
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.730878] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.730881] DMA: 3*4kB 3*8kB 3*16kB 4*32kB 3*64kB 1*128kB 1*256kB 1*512kB 2*1024kB 0*2048kB 2*4096kB = 11540kB
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.730900] DMA32: 62*4kB 4*8kB 3*16kB 4*32kB 2*64kB 0*128kB 1*256kB 0*512kB 1*1024kB 1*2048kB 1*4096kB = 8008kB
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.730908] Swap cache: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0, race 0+0
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.730910] Free swap  = 0kB
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.730911] Total swap = 0kB
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.730912] Free swap:            0kB
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.740886] 1048576 pages of RAM
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.740893] 21255 reserved pages
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.740894] 39897 pages shared
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.740895] 0 pages swap cached
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.740898] Out of memory: kill process 25246 (apache2) score 73450 or a child
Jun 23 21:19:01 vps528 kernel: [1182395.740913] Killed process 25246 (apache2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the VPS I am running doesn't have enough RAM for the amount of website and databases I am running on it. I'll be upgrading my VPS to one with 1GB of memory.

Comment: This isn't an answer. The whole point of a database is to be able to work with data that does not fit in memory. It a database gets OOM errors, that is a bug...